# Solid lines become dotted - flash 3d transform

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to 3d transform a floor tile pattern in flash, But when i do so the tile lines become dotted (dashed) here is the  [screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/i6ihc7.jpg)

Comment: make thicker lines. Or if it's an image, make sure smoothing is enabled.

Comment: yes its an image and smoothing doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is as LDMS said, thickening your lines (even if it is an image), or if you can, enable Anti Aliasing (which i think is what smoothing does)

As for why this happens, this is due to texture sampling. You will probably see that if you move your camera around the gaps/dots in the lines move. Now without going into too many details these are the basics:

Close to your camera the amount of pixel from your image that fit into a pixel on your screen will be less then 1, meaning that one pixel from your image is bigger then an actual pixel on your screen, so it will just display that color from the image. But what happens, if your image is so far away that multiple pixels from your image are so small that they combined fit into one pixel on your screen? With smoothing and Anti Aliasing you run an algorithm to combine colors and get en estimated result. But if you do not do this it will have to pick a color, say we have 2 pixels of black (your line) and 2 of the red background for the same pixel on screen, it will (randomly or based on some variable) pick a color and display it without regard of the other colors.

This is why you sometimes see your line and sometimes the background.